# Inserting Duplicate Keys into a 2-3-4 Tree

Tags: search, tree, key, b-tree

When inserting just a few duplicate keys into a 2-3-4 tree, it is rather easy to find the in-order successor, insert there, and keep the tree running smoothly. However, once many of the same key are added, the tree no longer can be searched the same way since you will have the duplicate key in both left and right children (eventually making it impossible to find some of them). How can this be avoided without using a secondary list to store duplicates? Does the search function or insert function need to be adjusted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keys in keyed data structures are unique by definition; things that aren't unique aren't (record) keys although they might be part of compound keys.

The most common - and easiest - way of handling the situation is to extend the key, either by using something appropriate contained in the record data or by adding some arbitrary disambiguating information (time stamp, counter, whatever) whenever a new 'key' is inserted into the tree.

If you put dupes into your 2-3-4 tree then you break its invariants and it is no longer a 2-3-4 tree (just a heap of data that strongly resembles one).

With careful coding it is certainly possible to implement 2-3-4 trees (or other B-Trees) that do not depend on records being uniquely identifiable; however, it's hard to see what the point might be. That's why every database system I've ever seen implements the solution above, i.e. adding something to the 'key' to make it unique.